# Jenkins fails build with 'error storing credentials'

Tags: jenkins, credentials, keychain

Im getting the following output, noticed that the error doesnt occur when only one build is running, there seem to be a conflict when other builds are running aswell. I have 2 builder.

`Using the existing docker config file.Removing blacklisted property: authsRemoving blacklisted property: credsStore$ docker login -u z*******t -p ******** https://docker.pkg.github.com`

`WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.`

`Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: The specified item already exists in the keychain.`

Comment: Seems like a solution is to delete from ~/.docker/config.json - "credsStore"

Comment: you should add this as an answer. I was banging my head for 3 hours. you saved me!

Comment: @RamPrakash you're welcome :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a solution is to delete from ~/.docker/config.json - "credsStore"